# Pasar código a Factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

Estoy trabajando con `Angularjs` y en concreto con `Factory`. En uno de mis `js` tengo un fallo porque es una copia de otro código que tengo con `$scope` pero ahora al usar Factory no se como solucionarlo.

Este es el código completo con el que estoy trabajando:

```
function formFactory() {

    var Respuesta = {

        cantidad: 0,
        plazos: 0,
        tipoCredito: "hipotecario"
    }
    var resultado = {};

    var respuesta = {};



    resultado.getRespuestaGuardada = function () {
        return respuesta;
    }

    resultado.getrespuesta = function (formulario, callback, $http) {

        console.log('llama aqui')

                respuesta.showMe = false;
                var baseurl = 'http://localhost:58498';
                var cantidad = 'cantidad=' + formulario.cantidad;
                var plazos = '&plazos=' + formulario.plazos;
                var tipo = '&tipo=' + formulario.tipo;

               $http.get(baseurl + cantidad + plazos + tipo).success(function (respuesta) {
                console.log('fin')
                  callback(respuesta);
              })
        };

        return resultado;
    }
```

Y aquí me indican que está el error. Supongo que es porque hay que usar otra cosa pero no tengo ni idea de como solucionarlo.

```
$http.get(baseurl + cantidad + plazos + tipo).success(function (respuesta) {
                console.log('fin')
                  callback(respuesta);
              })
```

Comment: Estaría bien saber que error te da y el código dónde registras el factory ```application.factory(...```

Comment: Al final el error era que no añadía la dependencia de $http al factory.

Comment: Autocontestate y marca tu respuesta como buena para que quede más claro de cara a busquedas futuras. @SilviaGarcia

Answer (score 0):

**Te falto el punto y coma.** 
 **error:** *console.log('fin')*
**correcto** *console.log('fin');*

```
$http.get(baseurl + cantidad + plazos + tipo).success(function (respuesta) {
    console.log('fin');
      callback(respuesta);
  })
```

Comment: recuerda console.log(); es una instrccion